# Error in NiFi RouteOnAttribute Expression

Tags: apache-nifi

This expression `${N_JOB:equalsIgnoreCase('DWDMBL0D','DWDMBL0F'):and(${LAST_RUN:equals('${custom_date}')}):and(${C_CURR_STA:equalsIgnoreCase('C')})}`
in `RouteOnAttribute` is throwing error. How can I include two values for N_JOB?

Comment: you should not use `${...}` for nested expressions

Comment: @daggett how do i write nested expressions then?

Comment: hold on. what is the error message? seems you have wrong function usage:
`N_JOB:equalsIgnoreCase('DWDMBL0D', 'DWDMBL0F')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` like this
.[here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) are details

```
     ${N_JOB:in('DWDMBL0D','DWDMBL0F'):and(${LAST_RUN:equals(${custom_date})}):and(${C_CURR_STA:equalsIgnoreCase('C')})}
```